# Highcharts - How do I keep both line points in from splitting between the two bar charts

Tags: highcharts

How do I keep both line points/markers in from splitting between the two bar charts but yet still have the ability to span both when values exceed initial bar value.

In the following example you will note that there are two line series that have the same values and thus I'm wanting the points/markers positioned one above the other but they are being split between the two stacked bars.
[image: stacked bars but line points/markers split]

If you comment out the first bar series and plot options (see comments in code) you will see what I looking achieve but want the stacked bars rendered as well as have the second data value shown to the left.
[image: line points/markers stacked but missing stacked bar series]

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbp5qvzh/58

```
var mychart = Highcharts.chart(
    'container', {

    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: '400px'
    },

    title: {
      text: null
    },

    xAxis: {
      lineWidth: 0, 
      tickLength: 0,
      opposite: false,
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },

        yAxis: {
      opposite: true,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
        enabled: false
      },
        labels: { 
        enabled: false
      },
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        formatter: function () {
          return '<div class="barLabel">' + this.axis.chart.xAxis[0].categories[this.x] + '</div>';
        },
        useHTML: true,
        verticalAlign: 'top', 
        align: 'left', 
        style: { 
            fontSize: '16px', 
          fontFamily: 'proxima-nova' 
        }
      }
    },    

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

        legend: {
        itemStyle: { 
        color: '#000000', 
        fontWeight: 'bold', 
        fontSize: '18px', 
        fontFamily: 'proxima-nova' 
      }
        },

    series: [

/** COMMENT 1 - START **/
        { type: 'bar', 
        name: 'background fller',
        pointWidth: 50,
        data: [6, 5, 7, 3, 6], 
        showInLegend: false, 
        animation: false,
        color: '#dde8f2', 
        dataLabels: { 
            enabled: false 
        }, 
        states: { 
            hover: { 
            enabled: false 
          } 
        } 
        },
/** COMMENT 1 - END **/

      { type: 'bar', 
        name: 'actual value',
        pointWidth: 50,
        data: [4, 5, 3, 7, 4], 
        showInLegend: false, 
        color: '#729bc3', 
        dataLabels: { 
          enabled: true, 
          align: 'left',
          style: { 
            textOutline: false, 
            color: '#000000', 
            fontWeight: 'bold', 
            fontSize: '16px', 
            fontFamily: 'proxima-nova' 
            }, 
            }, 
        states: { 
            hover: { 
            enabled: false 
          }
        } 
      }

    ],

/** COMMENT 2 - START **/
    plotOptions: {
      series: {                  
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: { 
            enabled: false 
        },
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }
      }
    }
/** COMMENT 2 - END **/

});

mychart.addSeries({ type: 'line', name: 'Indicator1', lineWidth: 0,  
data: [3.3, 2, 3, 6, 3], pointPlacement: 0.3, showInLegend: true, 
dataLabels: { enabled: true, allowOverlap: true, verticalAlign: 'top', align: 'right', color: '#ff0000', style: { textOutline: false } }, 
marker: { symbol: 'circle', fillColor: '#ff0000' }, 
states: { hover: { enabled: false }, }
});


mychart.addSeries({ type: 'line', name: 'Indicator2', data: [3.3, 2, 3, 6, 3], pointPlacement: -0.3, showInLegend: true, dataLabels: { enabled: true, allowOverlap: true, verticalAlign: 'bottom', align: 'right',  style: { textOutline: false }, x: 0, y: 0 }, lineWidth: 0, marker: { symbol: 'diamond', fillColor: '#000000' }, states: { hover: { enabled: false }, }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have both indicators in one stack group which makes the values in second indicator to add up with first one. If you want them to look like the second images in your question You should seperate their groups using `stack: value` option in their series. somthing like this: (note `stack: 0` in **indicator1** and `stack: 1` in **indicator2**)

```
mychart.addSeries({ type: 'line', name: 'Indicator1', lineWidth: 0,  
data: [3.3, 2, 3, 6, 3], stack : 0, pointPlacement: 0.3, showInLegend: true, 
dataLabels: { enabled: true, allowOverlap: true, verticalAlign: 'top', align: 'right', color: '#ff0000', style: { textOutline: false } }, 
marker: { symbol: 'circle', fillColor: '#ff0000' }, 
states: { hover: { enabled: false }, }
});


mychart.addSeries({ type: 'line', name: 'Indicator2', data: [3.3, 2, 3, 6, 
3],stack:1, pointPlacement: -0.3, showInLegend: true, dataLabels: { enabled: true, 
allowOverlap: true, verticalAlign: 'bottom', align: 'right',  style: { textOutline: 
false }, x: 0, y: 0 }, lineWidth: 0, marker: { symbol: 'diamond', fillColor: 
'#000000' }, states: { hover: { enabled: false }, }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3pfm8Laz/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.stack